# Adding Eclipse CDT to an existing Eclipse JDT installation

Tags: 11.04, eclipse

I'm a Java developer who wants to start with C/C++ now. I have an Eclipse JDT installation, and today added the CDT feature plugin from inside Eclipse (Help->Install new software..-> and so on)

I restarted Eclipse, but I cannot see the C/C++ perspective and cannot create anything else than Java project. Googled on it, but found nothing special. Then I opened a terminal and did a `sudo apt-get install eclipse-cdt`. Started Eclipse again but nothing changed. I know there are downloadable Eclipse CDT packs, but I would not like to use them.

What should I do?

Using: Eclipse Galileo on Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apt package will definitely not install CDT to your existing eclipse "install" unless you used apt originally.  Even then it still might not (not sure if it's supposed to).

Also, make sure that when you run eclipse you do

```
whereis eclipse
```

to make sure the path is pointing to the new eclipse-cdt version.

I usually do:

```
sudo updatedb
locate eclipse
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `Window->Open perspective->Other...` The CDT perspective *should* be there unless an error occurred while installing.

EDIT: Also make sure that Eclipse C/C++ Development Tools are listed in your installation details. `Help->About Eclipse SDK->Installation details`

Comment: CDT isn't listed, however there were no errors during installation and says it is installed already.

Comment: When I said CDT I actually meant C/C++, is C/C++ listed?

Comment: Of course. But only Debug, Java, Resources, etc. are listed, nothing related to C

Comment: I did a `sudo apt-get remove eclipse-*' and 'sudo apt-get install eclipse-cdt' and mysteriously I got back the same Eclipse JDT (!) without any C/C++ features..

Comment: Are CDT listed in installations details (check my answer edit)?

Comment: Yes, CDT is listed in the Installation details, if tried to reinstall says error, already installed. But cannot change to that perspective.

Comment: @jabal I'm no expert in Eclipse or any IDE for that matter, but try `purge` instead of `remove` (in `apt-get`), and, if you don't mind losing any settings, remove them from your home folder.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out that it was a workspace issue.  I created two workspace folders, one for java and another for C++.  Then I closed the java perspective, closed eclipse, opened again, selected c++ workspace, then was able to open the c++ perspective.